# How to inject session in spring data neo4j 4.2.x custom repository?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm migrating from spring-data-neo4j version 4.1 to 4.2.
On the application startup I'm getting an error:

`Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

repository.ActivityRecordRepository.java:

```
public interface ActivityRecordRepository extends GraphRepository<ActivityRecord>, ActivityRecordRepositoryCustom {}
```

repository.ActivityRecordRepositoryCustom.java:

```
public interface ActivityRecordRepositoryCustom {
   ...
}
```

repository.impl.ActivityRecordRepositoryImpl.java:

```
public class ActivityRecordRepositoryImpl implements ActivityRecordRepositoryCustom {

    private final Session session;

    public ActivityRecordRepositoryImpl(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    ....
}
```

My configuration:

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.example.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    ....        

    @Bean
    public EventListener eventListener() {
        return new CustomEventListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {       
        final SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(databaseConfiguration, "com.example.entity");
        sessionFactory.register(eventListener());
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

How to properly autowire session object to custom repository implementation?

I'm using:
Spring Version: 4.3.2.RELEASE
Spring Data Neo4j Version: 4.2.11.RELEASE

Comment: Does it work for you to autowire the `SessionFactory` instead of a `Session`?

Comment: @meistermeier no then it fails with this exception: ```Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.register(Lorg/neo4j/ogm/session/event/EventListener;)```

Comment: @Slava Sorry for my 5 cents but I'm just wondering why do you need to migrate to SDN4.2 when SDN 5.x already exists?

Comment: @alexanoid because sdn 5.x requires spring version 5+. My project using spring 4

Comment: https://neo4j.com/blog/spring-data-neo4j-4-1-applications/  I think it's an example that conforms to Neo4J and Spring versions  that you're looking for.

Comment: @alexanoid With SDN 5.x does not work either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356497/spring-data-neo4j-5-no-bean-named-sessionfactory-available